# Is it possible to make my indicator run on 30 second chart when I am using the 1 minute?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, rsi

I'm trying to have my indicator show me the values from the 30 second chart while I am using the 1 minute chart. Is this possible?

```
indicator("Double RSI", timeframe="")
lengthRSIfast = input.int(2, minval=1,title="RSI Fast")
lengthRSIslow = input.int(14, minval=1,title="RSI Slow")
overSold =  10 
overBought = 90 
src = input(close, title="Source")
rsifast = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSIfast)
rsislow = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSIslow)

plot(rsifast,color=color.green)
plot(rsislow,color=color.red)

signal = ta.cross(rsifast,rsislow)?rsislow:na
signalcolor= rsifast>rsislow?color.green:color.red
plot(signal,color=signalcolor,style=plot.style_circles,linewidth=2)
os=hline(overSold)
ob=hline(overBought)

alertcondition(signal, title="DubRSi cross")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. It is possible to request data from the lower timeframe, however, it is not recommended because some data will be lost.

> security function was designed to request data of a timeframe higher
> than the current chart timeframe. On a 60 minutes chart, this would
> mean requesting 240, D, W, or any higher timeframe.
>
> It is not recommended to request data of a timeframe lower that the
> current chart timeframe, for example 1 minute data from a 5 minutes
> chart. The main problem with such a case is that some part of a 1
> minute data will be inevitably lost, as it’s impossible to display it
> on a 5 minutes chart and not to break the time axis. In such cases the
> behavior of security can be rather unexpected.

You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#requesting-data-of-a-lower-timeframe) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try [security_lower_tf](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity_lower_tf) with [timeframe](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Timeframes.html?highlight=week#timeframe-string-specifications) "30S".